# appcelerator titanium iOS Interactive Notifications not work when closed app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I send an interactive push notification, it's working correctly when the app is on background, but when the app is closed (killed) and click on notification action the listner "remotenotificationaction" is not fired but rather Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications callback is, as if it was like a notification click

how I can receive it when the app is killed ? 
thanks

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: the bug is already reported https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20272